# How do I make a progress bar close when it reaches the end?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

The Visual Basic code I have closes the form when the progress bar's value reaches 5. The issue I'm having is that it closes the form immediately when the value is 5 and the green bar ever reaches the end of the bar. I want the progress bar to close the form when it reaches the end of the bar. The animation ever shows that it reaches the end of the progress bar.

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = 5
End Sub

Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Timer1.Interval = 1000
        ProgressBar1.Increment(+1)
        Select Case ProgressBar1.Value
            Case 5
                Timer1.Enabled = False
                Me.Hide()
                Form1.Show()
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: have you set the max to 5?  or if you mean close at max, case progressbar1.max maybe.

Comment: Simply add `ProgressBar1.Maximum = 5` to your Form2.Load()

Comment: Okay I did that and it does the same thing, I found out that if I don't have the hide function the green bar will go the whole way to the end. How to I get around the `Me.Hide()` function closing the form to early. I have tried `Thread.Sleep(2000)` but that doesn't fix the problem the way that i want it to.